# Request based dependency in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, multi-tenant

I am developing a multi tenant application. The tenant is resolved in a Request Listener, which looks more or less like the following:

```
/**
 * @Service
 * @Tag(name="kernel.event_listener", attributes={"event": "kernel.request", "method": "onRequest"})
 */
class TenantResolverListener extends ContainerAware
{
    public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        // some magic stuff to detect tenant...

        $tenant = new Tenant($request->getHost());
        $this->container->set('tenant', $tenant);
    }
}
```

To easily access the tenant configuration at any location in my application, I got the idea to register the tenant as a dependency in the dependency container.
The problem here is, that the "tenant dependency" is unknown at compile time and I can not  inject it directly into other services. (I have to inject the container and access the tenant configuration through the container (`$this->container->get('tenant')`)).

I think this is not the best solution at all, but I'm not quite sure, how to solve the problem. My ideas are:

1. Register a default tenant, which will be overwritten later in the TenantResolver.
2. Detect the current tenant anywhere earlier, but where / how?
3. Don't put the tenant configuration into the container

   1. and wrap the Configuration in its own service, which locates the current tenant and returns the configuration. (`$tenantResolver->getConfig()`).
   2. and ...?

If anybody has experiences hereby, it would be very kind to give me some tipps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make yourself a TenantFactory service and then make your tenant service use it.

```
tenant_factory:
    class:  MyProjectBundle\Entity\TenantFactory

tenant:
    class:  MyProjectBundle\Entity\Tenant # Not used but still needed
    factory_service: '@tenant_factory'
    factory_method: get # The container will call $tenantFactory->get() when $tenant is needed.

// Request
$tenant = new Tenant($request->getHost());
$tenantFactory = $this->container->get('tenant_factory');
$tenantFactory->set($tenant);

class TenantFactory
{
    protected $tenant;
    public function set($tenant) { $this->tenant = $tenant; }
    public function get()        { return $this->tenant; }
}

// Controller
$tenant = $this->container->get('tenant');
```

You do have to make sure that your listener is triggered before tenant dependent services are called but that should not be a problem.

And of course TenantFactory is not really a factory but you get the idea.  You actually could make it a real factory (or repository) and just have your request listener inject the host name.

=============================================================

Update: A few days after posting the answer I was reading the reference book (always dangerous) and came across the notion of a synthetic service.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html

No tenant factory is needed.  A synthetic service expects to have the object added via set.

```
# services.yml
tenant:
  synthetic: true

// Listener
$tenant = new Tenant($request->getHost());
$this->container->set('tenant', $tenant);
```